# I'm getting a 400 Error when attempting to import data into EPiServer

Tags: c#, iis, episerver

I'm trying to import two *episerverdata* files that are 2.6 GB & 6 GB onto a website that has no other content, and is just the source code of the website. I'm attempting to do this on a local development machine using IIS Express. However, whenever I attempt to upload either file, the file will hit 99%, and then show an HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request. The error says that ASP.NET detected invalid characters in the URL, but I don't see how considering it's just a file upload, and the name of the file is completely compliant, (Pages_ExportedFile).

I've attempted to increase IIS' file upload limit using the web.config of my project:

- maxRequestLength="40960"
- executionTimeout="7200"
- maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"

I've also attempted to upgrade the site slowly to ASP.NET Framework 4.6.1 from 4.5. I'm using EPiServer 10 right now, although I'm attempting to upgrade it to 11 to see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: Which exact version of epi 10 are you running now?

Comment: Hello @EricHerlitz! Sorry for not getting back to you sooner. It ended up that this was not the answer to my problem, but something else entirely. I'll be setting your answer as the correct question to help with future coders that might need help with this type of problem however.

Comment: You can post how you resolved the issue below and mark that as the answer as well.

Comment: @EricHerlitz To be fair, it had absolutely nothing to do with my issue listed above, which is why I think the answer to my problem is moot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**maxRequestLength** is set in kilobytes, if your file is 6.0 GB it should at least have the value 6291456,

**executionTimeout** is set in seconds, 7200 would mean two hours. This should be enough and I assume you set the element in the system.web section, ie.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="7200" />
</system.web>
```

**maxAllowedContentLength** is set in bytes, 6.0 GB = 6442450944 bytes

Since you are using IISExpress there are some limits

- depending on your version there may be actual storage limits
- you may need to tweak the applicationhost.config file in  `%userprofile%\Documents\IISExpress\config`. Depending on the implementation the settings set above may also apply to the iis configuration and the timeouts may actually come from iisexpress and not iis.

Comment: Thanks Eric! Unfortunately, this didn't solve my issue. I'm thinking now that it might not have anything to do with the file size. Would you have any suggestions as to why EPiServer Data files are having issues uploading?

Comment: @LinkChef try with some small files first and see if you still have problems. That may narrow down the problem